# How to create a view function for a URL that is not a part of any app?

Tags: python, django

I have  a Django project called "Reports". The projects will have three apps: "Report_1", "Report_2" and "Report_3".

I want to have a home page where the user could choose a report and respective app will be launched.

Therefore, I would write the project's `urls.py` like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Report_1.urls')),
    path('', include('Report_2.urls')),
    path('', include('Report_3.urls')),
]
```

and then create `urls.py` for each app.

However, such home page would be one level above the apps, so where do I write a view function for it? Or is this approach broken by design and I should try something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the project an app too and place the views.py for it in the same directory as the main urls.py.

Comment: Thanks. And where should I put the template for such view? I have tried creating `templates` folder in the same dir as project's `urls.py` (and now also `views.py`), then another folder with the project's name (just as it is done for the apps) and then placing the template there, but this results in "TemplateDoesNotExist" error.

Comment: @barciewicz: Include your project's name in INSTALLED_APPS. That's a pretty normal thing to do, we have it in all our projects.